# I am using .net core 2.1 with mongodb but i have this type error . Routing issue

Tags: routes, http-status-code-404

> Error 1:
>   For action: 'ContactManagerApi.Controllers.ContactApiController.GetContactList (ContactManagerApi)'
>   Error: While processing template 'api/[Contactinfo]/GetList', a replacement value for the token 'Contactinfo' could not be found. Available tokens: 'action, controller'. To use a '[' or ']' as a literal string in a route or within a constraint, use '[[' or ']]' instead.

I want to be able to hit `api/contactinfo/getlist`.  What can i change in Startup.cs or launchsetting or appsetting?

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[Contactinfo]")]
[ApiController]
public class ContactApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("GetList")]
    public ActionResult<List<ContactInfo>> GetContactList()
    {
        return _Repository.AsQueryable().ToList()
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is stating that `[Contactinfo]` is not a known ASP.NET Core routing token. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be able to hit `api/contactinfo/getlist` then remove the square brackets around `[Contactinfo]` from your route definition. The square brackets indicate that it's a [routing token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area-1).